# MapReduce reading two more columns from text file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to MapReduce and your feedback is appreciated. I have a text file that has data in foll. format -

---

```
State1  County1  Students#(Integer) Teacher#(Integer) Classrooms#(Integer)
State1  County2  Students#(Integer) Teacher#(Integer) Classrooms#(Integer)
State1  County3  Students#(Integer) Teacher#(Integer) Classrooms#(Integer)
State2  County1  Students#(Integer) Teacher#(Integer) Classrooms#(Integer)
State2  County2  Students#(Integer) Teacher#(Integer) Classrooms#(Integer)
State2  County3  Students#(Integer) Teacher#(Integer) Classrooms#(Integer)
```

---

I have written mapreducer that gives me the foll. output -

```
State1 Total<Students#>
State2 Total<Students#>
```

---

I need the same for Teacher and Classrooms cols - Final output needed:

```
State1 Total<Students#> Total<Teacher#>  Total<Classrooms#>
State2 Total<Students#> Total<Teacher#>  Total<Classrooms#>
```

Comment: Provide some absolute numbers/values to your examples. The example is not clear.

Comment: what is foll...? what have you tried?

Comment: @vignesh- here is data-

Comment: State County #Students #Teachers #Classrooms
CA  Conway  50 12  15
CA Grant 120 22 20
CA Miller 75 18 13
IL Rice  84  19  15
IL Millcreek 52 25 11
IL Saline 68 34 9
----> This is the data in the csv file    

State #Students   
CA 245   
IL 204  ----> I go this output with the MR i wrote  
    
    
State #Students #Teachers #Classrooms 
CA 245 52 48 
IL 204 78 35

----> I need this final output with MR

Answer (score 1):

You can try below too

```
public class MultiColSumDemo extends Configured implements Tool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MultiColSumDemo(), args);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

    getConf().set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", "  ");

    Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());

    job.setJobName("MultiColSumDemo");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MultiColMapper.class);

    job.setReducerClass(MultiColReduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("input/sum_multi_col"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("sum_multi_col_otput" + System.currentTimeMillis()));

    job.setJarByClass(MultiColSumDemo.class);
    job.submit();

    return 1;
}

class MultiColMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
        context.write(key, value);
    }

}

class MultiColReduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Iterator<Text> it = values.iterator();
        StringTokenizer st = null;
        HashMap<String, Integer> sumCol = new HashMap<>();
        String[] name = null;

        System.out.println(key + " " + values);

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(it.next().toString(), "  ");
            st.nextToken();
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                name = st.nextToken().split("#");
                if (sumCol.get(name[0]) == null)
                    sumCol.put(name[0], Integer.parseInt(name[1]));
                else
                    sumCol.put(name[0], sumCol.get(name[0]) + Integer.parseInt(name[1]));
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Entry<String, Integer> val : sumCol.entrySet())
            sb.append(val.getKey() + "#" + val.getValue());
        System.out.println(key + " " + sb);
        context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString()));

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide the code with what you have tried, so I will assume that you map by State and then sum up Student in the reducer.

The logic for summing the teachers and classrooms is exactly the same. 
Instead of producing a (key, value) pair, in which the value in an IntWritable, you can set the value to be a Text, in which you will appeend all the sums. Otherwise, you can define your own Writable class, which will consist of three ints (students, teachers, classrooms).

The same holds for the values of the map phase; instead of IntWritable, provide a Text (concatenation of the fields that you are interested in and which you will parse in the reduce phase), or a custom Writable class.

I suppose that you already have the logic for aggregating (summing) the counts, since it is exactly the same as you did for students.

Comment: Thx, vefthym. here is the code that sums the students column.. Mapper -    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     String[] split = value.toString().split(",");
    word.set(split[0]);
    if (split.length > 10) {
      try {
        count.set(Long.parseLong(split[11])); //students data in 11th col of the csv file
        context.write(word, count);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // cannot parse - ignore

Comment: reducer code-  private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();

 public void reduce(KEY key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,
                    Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   long sum = 0;
   for (LongWritable val : values) {
     sum += val.get();
   }
   result.set(sum);
   context.write(key, result);

Comment: @vefthyn - per ur suggestion, I changed the values to text in mapper separated by ','. How do I sum this text value? I can convert them into integer and convert them into string but i am getting stuck in code language.

Comment: mapper error..here is the code -->public class chsiprj extends Mapper<Text, String, Text, String> { private Text word = new Text(); private Text count = new Text();
   private Text count1 = new Text();   String sumcount = new String();
   protected void map(Text key, String value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
 String[] split = value.toString().split(",");
    word.set(split[0]);    if (split.length > 10) { try { count.set (split[11]);
        count1.set(split[12]);
        sumcount = count+ "," + count1;
        context.write(word, sumcount); }

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. I am able to get the output.

Mapper code

```
import java.io.IOException;


import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class Exercisemapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
{
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
        String orig_val=value.toString();
        String[] orig_val1=orig_val.split(",");
        String state_val=orig_val1[0];
        String other_counts=orig_val1[2]+","+orig_val1[3]+","+orig_val1[4];
        context.write(new Text(state_val),new Text(other_counts));
    }


}
```

Reducer code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class ExerciseReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> 
{
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
        Map<Integer,Integer> mymap=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        int myval=0;
        for(Text s:value)
        {
            String comma_values=s.toString();
            String[] comma_values_arr=comma_values.split(",");
            for(int i=0;i<comma_values_arr.length;i++)
            {
                if(mymap.get(i)==null)
                mymap.put(i,Integer.parseInt(comma_values_arr[i]));
                else
                {
                 myval=mymap.get(i)+Integer.parseInt(comma_values_arr[i]);
                 mymap.put(i,myval);
                }
            }
        }
        for(Integer finalval:mymap.values())
        {

            sb.append(finalval.toString());
            sb.append("\t");
        }
        context.write(key,new Text(sb.toString().replaceAll("\t$","")));        
    }
}
```

Driver Code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class ExerciseDriver {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        if(args.length!=2)
            {
            System.err.println("Usage: Worddrivernewapi <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
            }
        Job job=new Job();

        job.setJarByClass(ExerciseDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("ExerciseDriver");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(Exercisemapper.class);

        job.setReducerClass(ExerciseReducer.class);


        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }

}
```

And in driver code set number of reducers to 1.

Comment: thx much! this worked however the output is the entire csv file as it is.I need sum of the columns for each state (key)..any thought?

Comment: is the reducer getting ignored in this case?

Comment: You would be able to get the output based on state only. I got the output as CA 245 52 48
IL 204 78 35 . No the reducer would not be ignored instead a single reducer would be run since we need an aggregate of the map output.

Comment: bummer! unfortunately in my case I am not getting the output as ur getting

Comment: yes, i did and was able to execute the project..let me look at the driver code.thx

Comment: i am still getting all columns and rows from the the csv file..unable to get the sum of the columns for each state.i guess v can sum it in mapper only and pass on the output directly w/o reducer..

Comment: example of output -

Alabama 28414,22.1,24.3,62.5,11.6,1.6,52.2,46.8,0.4,0.3,3.1
Alabama 21516,16.8,24.6,63.3,10.9,1.2,76.8,22.5,0.3,0.1,1.4
Alabama 55725,11.9,24.5,62.1,12.1,1.3,97.1,1.5,0.5,0.2,6.3
Alabama 11055,26.2,24.7,63.2,10,2.2,27.8,71.4,0.4,0.2,5.9
Alabama 20766,20,25.6,58.5,13.6,2.4,57.5,41.9,0.2,0.3,0.9
Alabama 112141,16.4,24.1,61.6,12.7,1.5,78.3,19.7,0.4,0.8,2
Alabama 35460,16.2,24.8,59.5,13.5,2.2,60.8,38.6,0.1,0.2,1.2
Alabama 24522,15.2,21.9,61.4,15.2,1.4,93.3,5.5,0.3,0.3,1.1

Comment: also, in 2nd block i see space between state name and next column..this does not appear in 1st block

Arizona 181277,18,30.8,51.8,15.6,1.8,93,2.7,1.9,1.4,54.6
Arkansas        8903,14.2,24.7,61,12.6,1.7,85.7,13.5,0.4,0.1,1.8
Arkansas        20073,17.3,24.9,59.5,13.8,1.8,74.6,24.5,0.1,0.4,1.1
Arkansas        23178,17.8,25.9,60.2,12,1.9,71.3,27.8,0.1,0.3,3.8
Arkansas       40330,13.7,18.8,54.8,22.8,3.6,98,0.3,0.5,0.4,1